# Alphanumeric Puzzle multplication : $OW\times HE=WWW$

Tags: cryptarithm

$OW\times HE=WWW$
where $O,W,H,E$ are digits.

I've gathered that

$$W\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$E\in\{1,3,6,7,9\}$$

but I can't seem to move past it.

Comment: $~W=9~$ (for example) can easily be rejected, by exploring the max value of the possible two digit numbers $~OW \times HE.~$  One plausible plan of attack would be to forgo elegance, and investigate possible values of $~W.~$  Note that the RHS product must be a multiple of $~3,~$ which implies that at least one of the two LHS  factors must be a multiple of $~3.$

Comment: WWW is a multiple of 111, and therefore a multiple of 37.  Thus one of the 2-digit factors must be either 37 or 74 (and the other must be a multiple of 3).

Answer (score 1):

$WWW$ is a multiple of $111=3×37$, so $OW$ or $HE$ has to be a multiple of $37$. Thus four cases:

$HE=37\implies7×W\equiv W\bmod10\implies 6×W\equiv0\bmod10\implies W=5\implies15×37=555$

$HE=74\implies4×W\equiv W\bmod10\implies 3×W\equiv0\bmod10\implies$ no solution, we can't have $W=0$

$OW=74\implies74×HE=444\implies$ no solution, must have $HE\ge10$ to avoid a nonzero initial digit

$OW=37\implies$ let's see if the OP can work out the second solution.